# Space after images or title

Tags: spacing, graphics, titles, thesis

I am a LaTeX beginner. I am writing my thesis and used a template from my university. My problem is the space between figures and the text that follows.

Sometimes it’s good, sometimes too large. This is also true for the title and the text before and after (see attached image).

[image]

Comment: There are many related questions about this on this site. Apart from that, I recommend to ignore that for a while and better focus on the content of your thesis. You can address the "problem" later when you finished the actual work :).

Comment: i am sorry ,i should  say i wrote my thesis in latex not i am wring,now  i am in the last  phase before print. so for that i am now try to fix this issue.thank

Comment: For us to help you we need executable code to test things on.  There are too many different ways to affect spacing to tell which one is your problem.